# Best way to insert at the same time a row with an auto-increment ID and a row with foreign key references the auto-increment ID

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

let's make an example

we have a web site for a car dealer, the db has two tables

1- Person with an auto-increment ID and other useless attributes (name,surname,...)

2- Car with an auto-increment ID and an attribute ownerID that is a foreign key references Person
(plus other usuless attributes)

a new client comes in the car dealer and buy a new car,
now what we do is:

1- create a row in Person table

2- create a row in Car table but we don't know what is the ownerID

so my idea to do this is:

1- create a row in Person table

2- select the last insert ID in Person

3-create the row in Car table

I make these 3 statements in one single commit, but I think there is the possibility to have another insert of a new user between statement 1 and 2 that brings me to select the wrong ID

how do I proceed?

Comment: It's possible a dealer may sell a car more than once (from new and as second hand trade in) so a junction table may be more appropriate.

Comment: yeah thanks, using last_insert_id() it seems work quite well. I thought there was a easy way to do it.